# Returning String from Method Produces Undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an ES2015 module:

```
export default class ArrayCollection {

    constructor(items = []) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    search(query) {
        this.items.forEach(function (item, index) {
            if (query == item) {
                return `Your query ${query} was found in the array on the ${index} index`;
            };
        });

        return `Your array does not contain a ${query}`;
    }
}
```

And in my main.js I have this:

```
import ArrayCollection from './ArrayCollection';

let Numbers = new ArrayCollection([2, 4, 6, 8, 10]);

let searchResult = Numbers.search(4);

console.log(searchResult);
```

Why does the console.log return `undefined`?

I am trying to search an array for an item and if it is there to return it. I know that there are special methods in ES6, but I just want to know what is wrong with the above code.

Thanks.

**=== EDIT ===**

If you run above ES6 code through `webpack` or `rollup` it produces the following vanilla code that runs through any browser:

```
var ArrayCollection = function ArrayCollection(items) {
    if ( items === void 0 ) items = [];

    this.items = items;
};

ArrayCollection.prototype.search = function search (query) {
    this.items.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (query == item) {
            return ("Your query " + query + " was found in the array on the " + index + " index");
        }
    });

    // return `Your array does not contain a ${query}`;
};


var Numbers = new ArrayCollection([2, 4, 6, 8, 10]);

var searchResult = Numbers.search(4);

alert(searchResult);
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q4czh3n1/) that produces the same error. It would be nice if I could get a correction on the ES6 version instead of the compiled version.

Comment: In what environment do you get `undefined`? Brower, Node.js, Babel?

Comment: When I run above code through the browser after I compiled it with `webpack` or `buble` it returns `undefined`. I included a jsfiddle, hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

There are a two issues with your code:

1. Returning inside the `forEach` callback will only exit the callback, not the search function. Meaning even if you return within the callback, the result will always be `Your array does not contain a 4`.
2. Be careful with the `==` operator. Unless you're very familiar with coercion, I would recommend use use the triple equal operator instead (`===`). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

You could write your code even simpler and avoid your issues using `.indexOf`:

```
export default class ArrayCollection {

    constructor(items = []) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    search(query) {
        if (this.items.indexOf(query) > 0) {
            return `Your query ${query} was found in the array on the ${index} index`;
        };

        return `Your array does not contain a ${query}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not resolve problem, because in example method `search` return `undefined` not "Your array does not contain a 4" - its weird

Comment: Yes, I cannot reproduce that in any browser environment. Or Node.js for that matter.

Comment: And I get the same result in the Babel repl as well. Either way, the OP's code would not have worked the way they had wanted to.

Comment: Thank you for your code @nils, I am not really interested in the `index`. I just want to search an array for the query, if it exist, I want to return a string and if it does not exist I want to return another string. I updated my post with a JsFiddle.